# Adding TreeViewItems to a TreeView in WPF results in an Exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

Title covers it. I must simply be doing something incorrectly, but every example I've seen so far doesn't add the items any differently as far as I can tell. The exception is

**"InvalidOperationException"**

with the message

**"Element already has a logical parent. It must be detached from the old parent before it is attached to a new one."**

I'm using the two TreeViews, one to show the contents of a source folder, and one to show the contents of a destination folder. So far it seems the TreeViewItem generation works fine, but adding it to the TreeView causes the exception. Here's the code:

```
public InstallerWindow(string sourcePath, string destPath, List<InstallInstruction> instructions)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    TreeViewItem sourceItem = GenerateTreeView(new TreeViewItem(), sourcePath);
    foreach (TreeViewItem item in sourceItem.Items)
    {
        SourceTree.Items.Add(item);
    }

    TreeViewItem destItem = GenerateTreeView(new TreeViewItem(), destPath);
    foreach (TreeViewItem item in destItem.Items)
    {
        DestTree.Items.Add(item);
    }
}

public TreeViewItem GenerateTreeView(TreeViewItem parent, string directory)
{
    string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(directory);
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        TreeViewItem newItem = new TreeViewItem();
        newItem.Header = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
        parent.Items.Add(newItem);
    }

    foreach (string folder in directories)
    {
        TreeViewItem newItem = new TreeViewItem();
        newItem.Header = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(folder);
        newItem = GenerateTreeView(newItem, folder);
        parent.Items.Add(newItem);
    }

    return parent;
}
```

Like always, any insight is very appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `GenerateTreeView` you add some items to the `parent` TreeViewItem. Afterwards, in the `InstallerWindow` constructor you iterate over these items and add them to another TreeView, e.g. `SourceTree`. This cannot work since the items can only be contained in one TreeView.

Are you possibly intending this?

```
public InstallerWindow(string sourcePath, string destPath, List<InstallInstruction> instructions) 
{ 
    InitializeComponent(); 

    GenerateTreeView(SourceTree.Items, sourcePath));
    GenerateTreeView(DestTree.Items, destPath));
}
```